# OSM Web Wizard usage

Tags: python-2.7, openstreetmap, veins, sumo

Instead of manually counting number of vehicles and entering in OSM Web Wizard is there any possible way to interface it with a python code that run to count number of vehicles from a video clip?

Is there a possibility to link the python file of vehicle counting to the osmWebWizard.py in order to automatically feed the vehicle count?

In case of any code which could help for the same. Is there any possibility that Veins might help solve the issue?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The web wizard is meant as a starting point but not as a general scenario creation toolkit. The generated scenario is placed in your working directory and has a name corresponding to the current date like `~/programming/git/sumo/2018-03-14-08-43-44`. If you look into this directory you will find a build.bat which contains the calls to randomTrips.py which generate the traffic. If you want to change the amount of traffic you should change the period parameter `-p`. You can of course call randomTrips.py from your own script as well. The relation between the vehicle count in the Web Wizard and the period is explained here: http://sumo.dlr.de/wiki/Tutorials/OSMWebWizard#Demand_Generation.

Comment: Okay. Thanks for your assistance. For now this seems to be the answer to my question.

Comment: But in case I call the randomTrips.py frm my own script will it generate the scenario having vehicle flow where vehicles are not following one another but are same as in normal traffic ?

Comment: I want the generated scenario not to be a car following model where in every car is not followed by another according to a demand generation

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand that. Car Following is usually not used as term for a demand model it refers to the vehicle dynamics, how the car determines its speed or acceleration when following another one.